# How to update Eclipse ADT Bundle revision 22 to 23?

Tags: eclipse-adt

I'm a beginner in programming. I downloaded the `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321`, but when I restarted it, on the other day, it said "need to update to revision 23". I searched for many long hours for solution to this but I couldn't find it. I have already try the "Help -> Install new Software" from the site of eclipse download site. After I click next, it gives me an error:

[image: alt]

So, I deselected Android Native Development Tools so I can click next but after that it gives me another error:

[image: alt]

I selected all the options in that window, but the Next button seems to be unclickable. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

That is the version I use for development.
You will need to check the following:
- the size of the adt folder. Mine is greater than 7gb after extraction
- Then make sure you have two folders and a file after extraction of the adt
- Then for the update installation, try installing them one by one, since there is some dependency between the packages.